# Huggingface EncoderDecoder text generation repeats or deletes generated text ending

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am using a Huggingface EncoderDecoderModel with a Bert model as the encoder and a Bert model with LM head as the decoder to convert a phone sequence to a sentence (/huh-lOH/ -> Hello).

Everything works perfectly (0.17 Cross entropy loss, really good results) except at the end of the generated sentence (generated with `model.generate(input_ids, ...)`) . The ending either:

- Is perfectly fine (My name is Dan)
- Lacks some words (My name is) -> This is the most common case
- Adds repetition (My name is Dan is is Dan is) -> quite common too

Such specific bugs are usually easy to debug but I'm quite stuck. I was wondering if people around with better understanding of transformer models would have some intuition on the cause.

Thanks for any piece of help or advice

Comment: Just check some of the parameters of the [generate](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.generate) method (e.g. `temperature`, `repetition_penalty`...). This is not something you can debug because the next token is derived from the model weights.